# OpenMP: Nested parallelism inside three for loops

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, nested, openmp, nested-loops

The below code shows sementation fault if I used num_threads(..) and if I try with omp_set_num_threads(..)the following error pops out:
"**libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable**” 
The error also arises in case of num_threads (considering the outermost parallel region is removed).

**System Specifications:**

- XEON Processor with 2 sockets, 4 cores/sockets and 16 threads/core

**To sum up:**
I want to have nested parallelism such that outer loops have five threads running parallel and then each thread creates 20 more threads(so in total still less than what my system offers).

```
void assembly(){ 
    omp_set_nested(1);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(5)
    {    //omp_set_num_threads(5);

         for (int j=0; j<5; ++j) {
             int itr = nodesInLevel[j];

             #pragma omp parallel num_threads(20)
             {// omp_set_num_threads(20);

                 #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
                 for (int i=0; i<itr; ++i) {
                    int start =tree[j][i]->cStart[0];
                    int end  = tree[j][i]->cStart[1];
                    int size0   =tree[j][i]->cSize[0];
                    int size1   =tree[j][i]->cSize[1];
                    A->rook_Piv(start,end,size0,size1,tree[j][i]->rank[0]);
                 } 

                #pragma omp for //schedule(dynamic) 
                for (int i=0; i<itr; ++i) {
                   int start =tree[j][i]->cStart[0];
                   int end  = tree[j][i]->cStart[1];
                   int size0   =tree[j][i]->cSize[0];
                   int size1    =tree[j][i]->cSize[1];
                   A->rook_Piv(end,start,size1,size0,tree[j][i]->rank[1]);
               }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please NOTE:**

I know the following code is not described properly but the code was very large and therefore I wasn't able to mention it completely.The problem is not related to code descriton but more to nested parallelism.
So any suggestions can be helpful.

Comment: Xeon cpu has at most partial support for 2 threads per core. You may need to reorganize data if you mean to use simd parallelism.

Comment: *"The problem is not related to code descriton but more to nested parallelism."* - I disagree. There is no substitute for a [mcve] if you encounter a specific error. One basic thing: your outer loop isn't even an OpenMP worksharing loop - it's just a loop that is executed completely by 5 threads. Also your code formatting is absolutely horrible misleading.

Comment: There is no Xeon processor with 16 threads/core. There is actually hardly any CPU with such a level of hardware parallelism - the closest candidate is SPARC T5 with 8 threads/core. Your system probably has 16 hardware threads in total (2 sockets x 4 cores x 2 HT). Anyway, if on a Unix/Linux system, check the limits using `ulimit -a`. Notice the value for `stack size`, multiply it by 100 (threads), and compare with the value of `address space`.

Comment: Hristo is right to suggest that you consider total stack requirement but the stack per thread is omp_stacksize .  Typically it defaults to 4MB.  Perhaps you need much more, then the total among all threads could exceed upcoming.

Comment: Could exceed value set in ulimit